# hotels database of russia (russian language info)

Tags: database

does anybody see database of hotels in popular cities of russia in russian language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://bronni.ru
They even have an API, see http://remote.bronni.ru/default.aspx?Page=Documentation.ascx